# Цикличное заполнение отсутствующих записей

Tags: oracle, циклы, plsql

Представим две таблицы с таким набором данных.

Таблица `Table_s` Характеризует собой вид продукта, мы будем рассматривать яблоко.

```
CREATE TABLE table_s(
  s_id number,
  s_value varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO table_s VALUES
(10001, 'Яблоко'),
(10001, 'Огурцы');
```

| S_id | s_value |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | Яблоко |
| 10002 | Огурцы |

На яблоки есть заказы, она же `Table_o`, связываются они путем использоваться `S_id` через `fk_s_id` таблицы `Table_s`, тип связи - один `s_id` ко многим `fk_s_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_o(
  order_value varchar(20),
  fk_s_id number
);

INSERT INTO Table_o VALUES
('00/22', 10001),
('11/23', 10001);
```

| order_value | fk_s_id |
| --- | --- |
| 00/22 | 10001 |
| 11/23 | 10001 |

На каждый заказ можно задать свое количество яблок, количество можно задать через таблицу `Table_C`, связь идет по `order_value` таблицы заказов - `table_o`, так и с помощью связи с `S_id` таблицы `Table_s`, связь типа 1 к 1 в обоих случаях, но вот незадача...

```
CREATE TABLE Table_C(
  c_id number,
  fk_s_id number,
  fk_order_value varchar(20),
  c_count number
);
--p.s. Сверху уже написал триггер на инсерт для генерации id по секвенции,
-- нет необходимости генерировать ID самостоятельно для данной таблицы
INSERT INTO Table_C VALUES
(null, 10001, 00/22, 25);
```

| c_id | fk_s_id | fk_order_value | c_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | 00/22 | 25 |

Запись количества создана только на 1 заказ.

Следовательно при попытке запроса `c_count` на заказ `11/23` мы будем получать `null`.

**Необходимо реализовать процедуру, при котором можно будет обнаруживать отсутствующие записи, а после этого insert'ить их с количеством по умолчанию "1"**

Желаемый результат после исполнения процедуры

```
select * from Table_C
```

| c_id | fk_s_id | fk_order_value | c_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | 00/22 | 25 |
| 2 | 10001 | 11/23 | 1 |

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: @Akina ПЕРЕОформил свой вопрос в соответствии с сурсом.

Comment: Что, Оракл стал поддерживать вставку нескольких записей в INSERT .. VALUES? это в какой же версии?

Comment: @Akina, никто жеж не отменял LOOP'ы, разве нельзя в цикле каждую запись отработать?

Comment: Если Вы полагаете, что с Вас попросили код исключительно для того, чтобы Вы потрахались с оформлением - то совершенно напрасно. Выложенный код должен позволять скопировать его и сразу выполнить, не занимаясь дополнительной его рихтовкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table_C( c_id, fk_s_id, fk_order_value, c_count)
SELECT NULL, table_s.s_id, Table_o.order_value, 1
FROM table_s 
JOIN Table_o ON table_s.s_id = Table_o.fk_s_id
LEFT JOIN Table_C ON table_s.s_id = Table_C.fk_s_id 
                 AND Table_o.order_value = Table_C.fk_order_value
WHERE table_s.s_value = 'Яблоко'
  AND Table_C.fk_order_value IS NULL;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/JWrEHEkV